# How are compiled method calls that return a value?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

If I have a method which returns a value (for example the `Remove` method of `Dictionary` class returns a `bool`), what happens if I do not assign the return value to a variable? In other words, if I write `dictionary.Remove("plugin-01");` without assigning the result to a `bool` variable, what are the differences in compilation with respect to `bool b = dictionary.Remove("plugin-01");`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's look at a simple example and the IL code it is producing (courtesy of LinqPad)

```
void Main()
{
    Bar();
    Baz();
}

bool Bar()
{
  return true;
}

void Baz()
{
  Console.WriteLine("placeholder");
}
```

This produces the following IL:

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        UserQuery.Bar
IL_0006:  pop          //remove current value from evaluation stack
IL_0007:  ldarg.0     
IL_0008:  call        UserQuery.Baz


Bar:
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0001:  ret    

Baz:
IL_0000:  ldstr       "placeholder"
IL_0005:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_000A:  ret
```

You can see `Bar` is called and then a pop to remove the boolean return value from the evaluation stack - it's going nowhere. I had to update the example to include another method call to `Baz()` otherwise the pop would not be emitted, since the program ends.

Now let's look at a case where we actually use the return value:

```
void Main()
{
    bool foo = Bar();
    Console.WriteLine(foo);
}

bool Bar()
{
  return true;
}
```

This produces the following IL:

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        UserQuery.Bar
IL_0006:  stloc.0    //pops current value from evaluation stack, stores in local var
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     
IL_0008:  call        System.Console.WriteLine

Bar:
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0001:  ret
```

Ignore the `System.Console.WriteLine` part which is everything after and including `IL_007` - just had to add it so the compiler does not optimize away the use of the variable. You see that the result of the `Bar` method call is popped from the evaluation stack and stored in the local variable `foo`. That is the difference - either a `pop`, which grabs and drops the return value or a `stloc.0` to assign the result to a variable.

So if you do not need the results of a method call you should just ignore the result. Even if you assign the result to a variable and that variable is never used, the compiler might completely optimize away the variable and the assignment - at least in release mode (in debug mode most optimizations are disabled to improve your debugging experience).

Comment: If you remove `Console.WriteLine(foo)`, should the IL be equal to the first example?

Comment: Yes it is - it is optimized away (presumably) because the variable `foo` is never used.

Comment: In your first "This produces the following IL", I think you should include the POP instruction that follows the call. This clarifies that the method result is on the MSIL stack and the caller has to handle it somehow (even if "handling" it means explicitly throwing it away)

Comment: @CoreyKosak: I showed the complete IL output as produced by LinqPad - but you are correct - there should be a `pop`, in this case it just was not emitted because the program ended before making any other call.

Comment: @BrokenGlass : thx for great explanation !! one question though, Its usual to see Ldoc, Ldc etc. in IL before method call. I read them as pushing argument values to evaluation stack. However, for example callee method read this argument as Ldarg.0. Per behavior of Ldarg opcode - it loads argument on to stack. Isn't same argument pushed to evaluation stack twice ? I am sure am missing something basic here but not sure what :(

Answer (score 3):

The return value will simply be ignored, if you do not use it.

You could do something like

```
if(!dictionary.Remove("plugin-01")) {
    MessageBox.Show("Error: plugin-01 does not exist!");
}
```

If you do not care, you can safely write

```
dictionary.Remove("plugin-01");
```

Answer (score 1):

The call part is the same, but the assignment part is skipped in the IL. Take a look - here is a disassembly of a simple program:

```
var d = new Dictionary<int,int>();
bool a = d.Remove(5);
d.Remove(6);
```

The disassembly looks like this:

```
    bool a = d.Remove(5);
00000057  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-40h] 
0000005a  mov         edx,5 
0000005f  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx 
00000061  call        69106A00
// Here is the assignment part 
00000066  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],eax 
00000069  movzx       eax,byte ptr [ebp-4Ch] 
0000006d  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax 
    d.Remove(6);
00000070  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-40h] 
00000073  mov         edx,6 
00000078  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx 
0000007a  call        69106A00
```

The top four lines are common; the last three lines from the first call deal with the assignment; they are missing in the disassembly for the second call.